# Увеличивается количество знаков после запятой при использовании df.to_csv() для вывода DataFrame в CSV файл

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, python-3.7

Надо прочитать файл, заменить десятичный разделитель с запятой на точку и сохранить в новый файл.

Содержимое файла:

> 78512;0,756

Считываю в DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_csv('111.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf-8', decimal=',', header=None)
```

Смотрю содержимое DataFrame:

```
In [56]: df
```

> Out[56]:
>          0      1
>   0  78512  0.756

Записываю в файл:

```
In [57]: df.to_csv('222.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf-8', decimal='.', header=None, index=False)
```

В результате получаю в итоговом файле:

> 78512;0.7559999999999999

Судя по всему, искажение появляется в момент записи, т.к. при выводе содержимого в консоль наблюдаю значение идентичное входному.
На всякий случай пробовал округлять перед сохранением, но, увы, результат получается такой же.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Но вообще это вопрос представления чисел с плавающей точкой. Они всегда хранятся приблизительно, "округлить" их как-то можно только при выводе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь параметром [float_format](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df.to_csv(r"c:/temp/res.csv", sep=";", index=False, header=None, float_format="%.3f")
#     NOTE: ---------------------------------------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Класс!
Спасибо!